# CameraX preview view changes height automatically

Tags: android, android-camerax, android-bottomsheetdialog

I am trying to implement my Preview View inside a BottomSheet. Everything is working fine except that the preview size changes as show in below image.
[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgNE3.jpg)

As you can see the preview is getting out of the bottom sheet while I have set the Preview View height to 175dp. It changes to 469 dp at runtime.
Below is my XML of bottomsheet.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="nothing"

        app:scaleType="fitCenter">

    </androidx.camera.view.PreviewView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/capture"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is my java startCamera and bindPreview functions.

```
private void startCamera() {

        final ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(AddNotesActivity.this);

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                    bindPreview(cameraProvider);

                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    // No errors need to be handled for this Future.
                    // This should never be reached.
                }
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(AddNotesActivity.this));
    }
```

```
 void bindPreview(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                .build();

        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();

        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .build();

        ImageCapture.Builder builder = new ImageCapture.Builder();

        //Vendor-Extensions (The CameraX extensions dependency in build.gradle)
        HdrImageCaptureExtender hdrImageCaptureExtender = HdrImageCaptureExtender.create(builder);

        // Query if extension is available (optional).
        if (hdrImageCaptureExtender.isExtensionAvailable(cameraSelector)) {
            // Enable the extension if available.
            hdrImageCaptureExtender.enableExtension(cameraSelector);
        }

        final ImageCapture imageCapture = builder
                .setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_0)
                .build();

        mPreviewView.setScaleType(PreviewView.ScaleType.FILL_CENTER);
      
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(mPreviewView.getSurfaceProvider());

        Toast.makeText(this, ""+mPreviewView.getHeight()+"---"+mPreviewView.getWidth(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis, imageCapture);

        capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bitmap image = mPreviewView.getBitmap();
                Toast.makeText(AddNotesActivity.this, "Captured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
```

I need that preview view to stay inside the bottomsheet.

Comment: This is probably happening because PreviewView's using a SurfaceView underneath the hood. Could you set it to use a TextureView instead (call [PreviewView.setImplementationMode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView#setImplementationMode(androidx.camera.view.PreviewView.ImplementationMode)) and pass it [ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView.ImplementationMode#COMPATIBLE)).

Comment: Thanks dude  It really got my work done

Comment: @HusaynHakeem thanks it works. But SurfaceView is recommended in API >= 24. How come going against the Google recommendations is a way to resolve a seemingly unrelated issue with the preview height? :(

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina Fair point, even though the issue isn't really about the preview height, it's more about the surface the preview is rendered on. The need to use a TextureView in this scenario (PreviewView in a ViewPager) is more of a constraint of PreviewView, which stems from it handling both the view and camera stacks. Using a TextureView allows for certain behaviors which SurfaceView does not support (at least not with the way things are currently built in PreviewView). Using SurfaceView is a nicety, as it offers performance benefits, but there are certain cases it's not suited for.

Comment: @HusaynHakeem Could you copy your comment here to full answer below? I found this question and first time I didn't see your comment and close this page. Only second time I read your answer in comments